# Recovering a git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I accidentally did `git commit -a` rather than `git commit` on a conflicted merge. In an attempt to reset it, I did a `git reset --soft HEAD~`. This didn't do what I want. When I run `git status` I don't see the conflicted files. How do I get back to the pre-`git commit -a` stage?

```
f74ce47 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~                                   
e607086 HEAD@{1}: commit (merge): broken with (circular resolver   errors)
f74ce47 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from ec-myBranch to ec-MyOtherBranch
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way would be to make a hard reset to a pre-merge commit, then merge again.

To preserve work already done on conflict resolving, I'd recommend manually backing up the entire project as-is and using it to help with conflict resolution.

Comment: then I lose my work on the merge. how is that the easy way?

Comment: @CptBartender is assuming you have backed up your work. If you need to get specific commits, cherry-pick them from a pre-merge commit.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I didn't say it's going to be easy :P only easiest. Please see my update in the answer.

Comment: It's a merge with 1,000 conflicted files. That's certainly not the easy way. I mean, right off the bat resolving the rest of these badly merged files manually would be easier and that's what I'm doing. I just want to know what to do. "git commit -a[valanche]" if you're in a conflicted merge? There is no going back? That can't be right.

Comment: Unfortunately, it *is* right: the merge state is recorded in the index, and after the commit, the resolved-vs-unresolved state from the index is gone.  (Normally if you run `git commit` *without* `-a`, it rejects your attempt to commit due to the unmerged index entries, but `-a` resolves them.)

Comment: What you're looking for is an uncommitted state, or more specifically, a state just before commit. By design, such state is not stored in the repository.

Side note: if you need to make a complex merge that involves thousands of conflicted files, then you've blown off your foot with a sawn-off long before typing that `git commit -a`.